# Understanding two sided t-test

Tags: statistics, self-learning

Assume we have two search engines, A and B. I get a list of scores for 10 different queries. Now, I model this with a t-test in order to test significance.

These are my hypothesis:

$H_0: B-A=0$

$H_1: B-A>0$

I obtain $t=1.0803$. My Critical significance level is $\alpha=0.05$ and the critical value is $cv=2.262157$.

Now, drawing the graph, how can I conclude if my hypothesis should be rejected? My assumption is that since my t value is lower than cv, then the hypothesis is rejected. Is this correct? What about the two sides? Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information provided, this must be a two-sided paired t-test, and
you must be testing $H_0: \mu_B - \mu_A = 0$ against the alternative
$H_1: \mu_B - \mu_A \ne 0.$ Also, you have 
$T = \sqrt{10}(\bar B - \bar A)/S_{B-A} = 1.0803.$ (At the end
you mention a two-sided test, but you have written the alternative
for a one-sided test. I suspect some problem using TeX here.)

In these circumstances, you would reject $H_0$ only if $|T| > 2.262.$ But your $T$-statistic
is too near to $0$ for you to reject. (So your supposition about
when to reject is wrong.)

The critical value 2.262 is for a two-sided test at the 5% level:
95% of the area under the density curve of Student's t distribution (with $n - 1 = 10 - 1 = 9$ degrees of freedom) lies between
-2.262 and +2.262. Thus, the total area remaining in *each* tail
is 2.5% and the total area remaining in *both* tails together
is the significance level 5%.

Comment: can you explain why this is a two-sided test by looking at the hypothesis? should I not reject if t < 2.262 ? I am very confused :(

Comment: A t test can be (a) left-sided (null has $=$ or $\ge$ and alternative has $<$), in which case you reject for small, negative, values of T; (b) right-sided (null has $=$ or $\le$ and alternative has $>$), in which case you reject for large values of T; or (c) two-sided (null has $=$ and alternative has $\ne$), in which case you reject for T far from 0. Title says two-sided, your cv is for a two-sided test with DF=9, $\alpha = .05$, so I assumed $>$ in statement of alternative must be a typo. Rejecting for T < 2.262 makes no sense in _any_ of these cases; for (a) it would be rej for T < -2.262.

Comment: Bruce I really appreciate your explanation, thanks for your time.